# How do do you make an Hourglass pattern?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make an hourglass, but I can't get the code for the hourglass right. What am I doing wrong? This is a shorter version of the original code.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int number;
    cin >> number;

//Hourglass

   for (i = number; i > 0; i--)
   {
       cout << endl;
       for (int j = number; i < j; j--)
       {
           cout << " ";
       }
       for (int j = 0; i > j; j++)
       {
           cout << "*";
       }
       for (int j = 0; i > j; j++)
       {
           cout << "*";
       }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < (number - (i + 1)); j++)
       {
           cout << " ";
       }
       for (int j = 0; j < (2 * i + 1); j++)
       {
           cout << "*";
       }
       for (int j = 0; j < (number - (i + 1)); j++)
       {
           cout << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Surely you need sand and glass to make an hourglass - Or am I misunderstanding the description of the problem

Comment: -_-   Alright I have to admit that was a well placed joke.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make an hour glass out of asterisks.

Comment: But why are you posting your homework on a site?

Comment: I wasn't trying to cheat or anything. I just code get the last mistake of my code fixed. I also realized that I messed up on the design of the hourglass.

Comment: Do you not know how to use google? : http://blog.grkweb.com/2014/04/c-hourglass-pattern.html -- literally the third result when googling  "print hourglass in c++".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your first for-loop. What you need to do is move

```
cout << endl;
```

to the bottom of the loop so that it creates a new line before entering the second loop.

```
    for (int i = number; i > 0; i--){
        for (int j = number; i < j; j--)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; i > j; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        for (int j = 0; i > j; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (number - (i+1)); j++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= (2 * i) + 1; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

this should give you an hourglass like so

```
**********
 ********
  ******
   ****
    **
    **    
   ****   
  ******  
 ******** 
**********
```

Comment: also, in your second half of the hour glass, the third for-loop is unnecessary. It is adding space to the right side of the hourglass which you can just leave as empty space and get the same results. It will make your program more efficient by doing less!

Answer (score 0):

Following code will print the hourglass ( * ) pattern on screen. Variable *size* is the height of the hourglass to be printed. Compile the code using g++ compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  int row, col;
  int size;
  int diagA, diagB;

  std::cout << "Enter height of the hourglass ";
  std::cin >> size;

  for ( row=0; row<size; row++ ) {
    for ( col=0; col<size; col++ ) {

      diagA = row;
      diagB = size-row-1;

      if ( diagA <= diagB ){
        if ( col >= diagA && col <= diagB )
          std::cout << "*";
        else
          std::cout << " "; 
      }
      else {
        if (  col >= diagB && col <= diagA  )
          std::cout << "*";
        else
          std::cout << " ";
      }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```